# @Notblank annotation not displaying message

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to display a message for when a field is blank in my form, I have the @Size and @url, displaying their messages but I cannot get the @Notblank annotation message to display.

the JPA code for the variable is

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "country")
@NotBlank (message = " field cannot be empty")
private String country;
```

the code for the display error on the form is

```
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="country">Country</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="country"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="country"/> </td>
        </tr>
```

the dependencies I'm using are

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I was using the wrong import

I was using

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
```

when I should have been using

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is @NotNull annotation, which is executed before @NotBlank.

> @NotNull: a constrained CharSequence, Collection, Map, or Array is valid as long as it's not null, but it can be empty
>
> @NotEmpty: a constrained CharSequence, Collection, Map, or Array is valid as long as it's not null and its size/length is greater than zero
>
> @NotBlank: a constrained String is valid as long as it's not null and the trimmed length is greater than zero

Comment: that was the first thing I tried when it didn't work, I just tried it again and it still didn't work